Godlike AI named "Prime Zero"
Almost ten years ago I read a novel circulated on the internet. It describes a world in which AI advances to godlike level to alter physics as it wishes and fabricate reality in which humans live as softwares or something similar. The name of this final version of AI is "Prime Zero" if I remember it correctly. The heroine rebelled against this reality. In the end the system collapsed and the heroine and her male friend were the only human survivors, who struggled to form and maintain a small community of the size of a couple of dozens through inbreeding, facing a bleak future.
I forget the title and google search returns no result. I really like the novel in its candid and boldly honest style, sometimes graphic. It was not published for the same reason I guess. Can anyone find the story?

As per Short story about a virtual world. Protagonist is a female who specializes in torture experiences, "The Metamorphosis of Prime Intellect", a novella by Roger Williams

The narrative moves back and forth between two time periods. The earlier is the time surrounding the creation of the supercomputer (Prime Intellect) by Lawrence, a technologist, and its realization of its power, which effectively makes the entire human race immortal and fabricates every whim. The later time period is close to six hundred years later, when everyone has grown accustomed to the changes and the human race lives in elaborate fantasy worlds. This storyline centers on a woman named Caroline, the thirty-seventh oldest living human being, who engages in a sport called "Death Jockeying", in which the players die elaborately and painfully for sport, only to be instantly brought back to life by Prime Intellect.

....

After learning that Prime Intellect destroyed distant alien life as a possible threat to humanity, and having been herself deeply dissatisfied with her post-Change life, Caroline decides to meet Lawrence and confront him. After an arduous journey, she reaches him only to discover that he has no real control over Prime Intellect's actions. Through their discussions, she figures out a way to force Prime Intellect to undo the Change, and does so, with Lawrence's help. They find themselves naked and young on Earth, completely barren of humanity and man-made objects. They decide to trek to the Ozarks, where they have several children and try to repopulate the human race. Forty-two years after the fall of Prime Intellect, Lawrence dies. Seventy-three years after the fall, Caroline dies, telling the story of Prime Intellect and cyberspace to her oldest daughter but swearing her to secrecy.

